# Why is the paint peeling and brown spots appearing on my ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, water-damage, cracks

I'm renting an apartment.

- The paint on my ceiling is slowing peeling and I see small brown spots on my bathroom ceiling.
- My bedroom closet ceiling is showing a lot of cracks and discoloring.
- The closet is underneath my upstairs neighbor tub.

At one point there was a huge water leak in my ceiling hallway, while I was at work. Fortunately, my brother was home and found out the upstairs neighbor left the water running in the bathroom. Could this be the possible reason?

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rZaOWi0k1EcBu7V80DQzzlIPfaF5oi2Z?usp=drive_link

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Alhaj! Can you be a bit more specific about what you're asking? It seems like you've already identified an issue that is continuing to get worse, and its most likely cause. Do you want to know more about investigating, or repairing? And depending on your situation, shouldn't the answer be "contact your landlord"?

Comment: @JayMcEh I want to know what is the likely cause...for example, there was a huge water leak in my ceiling hallway, while I was at work. Fortunately, my brother was home and found out the upstairs neighbor left the water running in the bathroom. Could this be the possible reason?

Comment: I mean... if the damage wasn't there... then there was a water leak and the damage now exists.... if it smells like a duck and walks like a duck... its probably a duck. :) 

Either way. I would make sure your landlord deals with this asap. Not just for your sake but for his also as if there is severe structural damage it could cause further issues to the building's integrity at a later stage.

Comment: If your pics are too big, you can upload them to imgur.com then post the links here. Someone will embed them for you. This post becomes useless without them once you've decided you don't need them anymore and delete them from your google drive.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities:

- There was more water damage from the previous leak than was originally thought and it's now starting to appear.
- The original water wasn't dried thoroughly and is continuing to seep through causing more damage.
- There's another water leak, this one a small drip, and it's slowly causing damage.

No matter the case, since you're renting, it's on the building owner/maintenance to deal with this. Get them over ASAP and show them what's happening and ask them to take care of it.

Be aware that it could take *days* with ceilings & walls open to get everything thoroughly dried out before they can start to close things up again. Also, they will have to find the source of the water and fix that, or this will simply continue to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your upstairs neighbor has a leak in the bathroom.  Could be as simple as caulking on the floor being damaged and allowing water splashing out of the tub/shower to leak through the floor, could be a water supply leak, could be a tub/shower drain leak.